# Error in bash time comparison

Tags: bash, shell, date, scripting

I have a bash script that creates a file with a timestamp as the name.  Once some time passes, it is supposed to pick up that file and do something with it.  I want it to pick it up after two hours, but for some reason, it is picking it up after 57 minutes (and 6 seconds).  Can anyone point me to an error in my logic or assumptions?

Here are the details:
I have a variable set to 2 hours (7200 seconds):

```
SERVICE_DURATION=${SERVICE_DURATION:-7200} # seconds
```

I am setting the filename equal to the Unix timestamp concatenated with nanoseconds:

```
active_name=`date +%s%N`
echo "${1}" >> ${ACTIVE_DIR}/${active_name}
```

I then loop forever until the time is right:

```
while true
do
    for fa in ${ACTIVE_DIR}/*
    do
        if [ $(basename ${fa}) -le $(($(date +%s%N) - ${SERVICE_DURATION} * 1000000000)) ]
        then
            exec 6< "${fa}"
            read old_port <&6
            read old_host <&6
            read old_config <&6
            exec 6<&-

            logger -p daemon.info "Recycling port ${old_port}."
            start_remote_service "${old_port}"
            stop_remote_service "${old_port}" "${old_host}" "${old_config}" "${fa}"

            sleep 2
        fi
    done
    sleep 30
done
```

I can't see what is wrong with this.  The filename (`$(basename ${fa})`) shouldn't be less than the current time minus the specified duration in nanoseconds (`$(($(date +%s%N) - ${SERVICE_DURATION} * 1000000000))`) until the duration has passed.

In order to keep the script from constantly checking, there is a `sleep 30` at the end of the loop, so it could be that the time is somewhere between 56:36 and 57:06.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Why are you concerned with nanosecond precision in these timestamps?

Comment: Try putting `set -x` in your script so you see what it's doing.

Comment: @chepner He's probably just trying to ensure no duplicates.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to avoid duplicates.  If there were a quick way to get tenths or hundredths of a second, I think that would suffice.

Comment: You also don't show an infinite loop, but one that checks each file once, then the loop exits.

Comment: I will edit to include the whole loop.  Left it out for brevity.

Comment: `date +%T%2N` will print out hundredths of a second. Use `%3N` for thousandths. Or `date +%s%2n` will match your example.

Comment: I am trying @ryanpcmcquen's suggestion.  I'll let you know in 2 hours (or 57 minutes) :)

Comment: Ok.  I tried removing the nanoseconds entirely.  The filenames are now just the number of seconds since the epoch.  It is still recycling at 57 minutes.

Comment: Ok.  It appears that a second copy of the script got orphaned and kept running.  The interval was set to just under an hour.  It was picking up the files and processing them.

Comment: Should I delete this question, since the error turned out to be something else entirely?